# String encryption using high order function map

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, higher-order-functions, map-function

I have written the following string encryption code. But I want to be able to take the encryption key from the keyboard using (read) instead of using a hard coded value. But I can't do it because map takes a list as an argument.

```
#lang racket

(define character-encryption
  (lambda (ch)
    (if (char-alphabetic? ch)
        (character-rotation ch 3) 
        ch))) ; non-letter will not be encrypted.

(define character-rotation
  (lambda (ch num)
    (integer->char (+ (char->integer ch) num)))) ; key=3

(define string-encryption
  (lambda (str) 
    (list->string (map character-encryption (string->list str)))))
```

UPDATE

```
> (string-encryption (read))
"foo bar"                        ; <- entered
"irr edu"                        ; output
```

UPDATE

```
#lang racket

(define character-encryption
  (lambda (key)
    (lambda (ch)
      (if (char-alphabetic? ch)
          (character-rotation ch key) 
          ch)))) ; non-letter will not be encrypted.

(define character-rotation
  (lambda (ch num)
    (integer->char (+ (char->integer ch) num)))) ; key=3 (I want to read this number)


(define string-encryption
  (lambda (key str) 
    (list->string (map (character-encryption key) (string->list str)))))
```

Comment: I want to read the encryption key. In above code it is hard coded as 3.I don't want to read the string.

Comment: like (string-encryption "foo bar" (read))

Comment: Thank you so much. My first time using stackoverflow. You really helped me out. Thanks the updated procedures worked.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read-line` to read a line. The result is a string.

Read more here:
[Docs on read-line](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-line%29%29)

Comment: Then enter the strings as  "foo bar"

Comment: I just need to read the encryption key as input using read not the string. But I can't pass it to the character-encryption procedure because it is called using map.

Comment: Ah - it's the number 3 you want parameterized. See the updated suggestion.